# HEX2OCT formula in MS Excel returns incorrect result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

While converting the hexadecimal value "FFFFFFFF00" into octal value using Hex2Oct of MS Excel, it should return "Error string" as per the rules mentioned [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HEX2OCT-function-54d52808-5d19-4bd0-8a63-1096a5d11912):

> If number is negative, HEX2OCT ignores places and returns a 10-character octal number.
>
> If number is negative, it cannot be less than FFE0000000, and if number is positive, it cannot be greater than 1FFFFFFF.
>
> If number is not a valid hexadecimal number, HEX2OCT returns the #NUM! error value.
>
> If HEX2OCT requires more than places characters, it returns the #NUM! error value.
>
> If places is not an integer, it is truncated.
>
> If places is nonnumeric, HEX2OCT returns the #VALUE! error value.
>
> If places is negative, HEX2OCT returns the #NUM! error value.

But it computes and returns as "7777777400" without considering the rules/remarks mentioned in the link.

For example:

While calculating HEX2OCT,

As per Excel rule, If number is positive, it cannot be greater than 1FFFFFFF(hex)<->3777777777(oct)<->536870911(decimal).

But while calculating the HEX2OCT for FFFFFFFF00(hex) <-> 7777777400(oct) <-> 1099511627520(decimal).

Here the hex value FFFFFFFF00 is greater than  1FFFFFFF, but MS Excel does not return the error string instead it returns the converted octal value.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2):

`FFFFFFFF00` is actually well within the range of `hex2oct` because it is a negative number.

According to that documentation the largest negative number it can handle is `FFE0000000` which when converted to decimal is `-536870912`. Converting your "big" hex over to decimal yields `-256`.

The reason the value of `FFFFFFFF00` looks so big is because it's a negative number. The first bit is set to 1 (when converted to binary) which signifies that the number is negative. Negatives are computed in binary using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) which is found by flipping each bit and then adding 1 to the number.

---

Undoing the two's complement:

For your big number, the binary representation is:

```
 1111111111111111111111111111111100000000
```

Subtracting `1`:

```
 1111111111111111111111111111111011111111
```

Flipping all the bits:

```
 0000000000000000000000000000000100000000
```

Which is 256

So.. basically if the hex looks big, but the first bit is `1` then it's actually a small negative and well within your range of allowable values.

Lastly, when you `hex2oct` you don't get a negative sign for these because we are still not in decimal notation. The first bit of your octal is still a `1` (when converted to binary) since it's still the same number, just represented in a different counting system.

Answer (score 1):

The clue lies earlier in the documentation page you quote:

> The `HEX2OCT` function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> **Number**    Required. The hexadecimal number you want to convert. Number cannot contain more than 10 characters. The most significant
>   bit of number is the sign bit. The remaining 39 bits are magnitude
>   bits. Negative numbers are represented using two's-complement notation.

The hex value `FFFFFFFF00` corresponds the binary value

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000
```

and as the documentation says, "the most significant bit is the sign bit ... two's complement notation". So this value represents a *negative* number. By the rules of two's complement, it actually represents `-256`. And this is fine, because it is not "less than `FFE0000000`", as `FFE0000000` is `-2097152`.

If you actually want to treat `FFFFFFFF00` as an *unsigned* quantity, and get the octal representation of decimal `1099511627520`, you'll need to use another method.